# How to prove a function fulfills the necessary conditions of existence of a Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given, say, $f(t)=e^{-3t}$ or $f(t)=tan(t)$, how could I prove that a Laplace transform exist? In order to prove its existence, it must fulfill two conditions: being piecewise continuous and being of exponential order. But how do I go about proving it, what would be the process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) read the definitions of those conditions (2) check if they apply to the function-at-hand. What more do you expect?

Comment: @paul sinclair For starters, an example. I've been googling and all I found are assertions like "this is piecewise continuous because it's obvious it is" and not a formal proof. The "check if they apply" is what am struggling with. If it were obvious to me, I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: These are differentiable where they are defined. Do you remember what that implies?